# Android - Tamagotchi game background service

Tags: android, android-intent, unity-game-engine, android-service

I try to build a Tamagotchi game with Unity for Android. The Tamagotchi has a food attribute that should go down even when the Game is closed.

So my approach would be build a IntentService that holds the variables, increase and decrease them if needed. For Batterie reasons i would use Alarm manager to start the Service only every 10 minutes if the App is closed. If the app is started it would bind the Service so it never closes and i can get the Variables.

Is there a more efficient way to handle this? I dont want my app to battery drain too much.

€: 
If the food gets low it should also display a notification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is indeed a more efficient way to handle this.

Why don't you just save a timestamp when the user closes the app and calculate the time passed when the user opens the app again?
Then you can calculate the new food attribute you're done.

Edit: If you want to show notifications if the food is low you need the alarm manager.

Here is some example code:

```
public static void registerAlarm(Context context) {
Intent i = new Intent(context, YOURBROADCASTRECIEVER.class);

PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,REQUEST_CODE, i, 0);

// We want the alarm to go off 3 seconds from now.
long startTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
startTime += 60000;//start 1 minute after first register.

// Schedule the alarm!
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, startTime, 900000, sender); // 15min interval

}
```

Comment: I see a problem here, depending on the features that @raodis wants, maybe he wants send a notification about the status of the Tamagochi. I mean, if the user don't play for example 5h.. the tamagochi will be very hungry, so the app could notify with an alert. If roadis want some feature like this, you answer will be not "valid". :(

Comment: If the food gets low it should also display a notification. Sorry forgot to write that

Comment: Didn't thought about that. Well then you have to go with the background service and the alarm manager.

Comment: Did anyone of you ever programmed an application like this and can you tell me how much Batterie it drained?

Comment: If you let it run every 10-15 min it shouldn't drain much at all. To measure the power consumption I recommend: https://developer.qualcomm.com/mobile-development/increase-app-performance/trepn-plug-eclipse

Answer (score 2):

You can also calculate when the Tamagotchi will be hungry just before the game is closed and set alarm only to that point to show notification.. unless the game opened again so you clear all notifications.